# Simple Injector - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: userManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simple-injector

I'm trying to get ASP.NET Identity setup with Simple Injector and I'm having problem after problem.  I think I'm getting close, but now I'm getting an error saying

> Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: userManager
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: userManager
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: userManager]
>      Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`2..ctor(UserManager`2 userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) +81
>      ILETSB.MCLETC.UI.ApplicationSignInManager..ctor(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager) in MCLETC.UI\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs:42
>      MCLETC.UI.ApplicationSignInManager.Create(IdentityFactoryOptions`1 options, IOwinContext context) in MCLETC.UI\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs:53
>      Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryProvider`1.Create(IdentityFactoryOptions`1 options, IOwinContext context) +14
>      Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__5.MoveNext() +89
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
>      Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__7.MoveNext() +179
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
>      Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__12.MoveNext() +180
>      Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
>      Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
>      System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +389
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

I'm getting the error message here:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Startup class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app, Container container)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => container.GetInstance<ApplicationUserManager>());

        // Nothing modified below (template code)
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
    }
}
```

SimpleInjectorInitializer:

```
public class SimpleInjectorInitializer
{
    /// <summary>Initialize the container and register it as MVC5 Dependency Resolver.</summary>
    public static Container Initialize(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = GetInitializeContainer(app);

        container.Verify();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

        return container;
    }

    private static Container GetInitializeContainer(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

        // IoC for ASP.NET Identity
        container.RegisterInstance(app);

        container.Register<ApplicationUserManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register(() => new ApplicationDbContext("Your constring goes here"), Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(() => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(container.GetInstance<ApplicationDbContext>()), Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.RegisterInitializer<ApplicationUserManager>(manager => InitializeUserManager(manager, app));
        container.Register<SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>, ApplicationSignInManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register(() => container.IsVerifying ? new OwinContext(new Dictionary<string, object>()).Authentication : HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication, Lifestyle.Scoped);

        // Register all controllers
        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        //Register Modules
        BusinessModule.RegisterServices(container);
        WebModule.RegisterServices(container);

        return container;
    }

    private static void InitializeUserManager(ApplicationUserManager manager, IAppBuilder app)
    {
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        //Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator()
        {
            RequiredLength = 8,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 3;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });

        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();

        var dataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
    }
}
```

Both `AccountController` and `ManageController` are setup similar to this:

```
    private SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string> _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
```

Am I registering something wrong for the `ApplicationUserManager`?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and exception details of the exception and *all* its inner exceptions.

Comment: @Steven Thank you.  I just updated the post.  The inner exception is just `null`

Comment: Don't you need to inject the dependencies for AccountController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you analyze the stack trace, the problem should become clear:

- The constructor of `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager<TUser, TKey>` is passed a `null` value for the `userManager` constructor parameter.
- The `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager<TUser, TKey>` constructor is called from the constructor of your application's `ILETSB.MCLETC.UI.ApplicationSignInManager` by passing the `userManager` parameter through.
- Thew `ILETSB.MCLETC.UI.ApplicationSignInManager`'s constructor is invoked from within the `ApplicationSignInManager`'s own `Create` method.

In other words, the static `ApplicationSignInManager.Create` method is supplying the `ApplicationSignInManager` constructor with a null value.

This is how far the analysis can go, because you haven't provided the details of the `Create` method.

Try debugging the `Create` method by placing break points to analyze what's going on and why the value is `null`.

Comment: Thank you Steven.  I updated the post to provide the Create method, this is what was automatically generated.  I will try debugging it also.

Comment: I ended up commenting out the `Create` method, and in the `ConfigureAuth` method in `Startup` I added the line `app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => container.GetInstance<ApplicationSignInManager>());` and removed `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);`.  I believe that fixed it.